# Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,BlockParser> System.Web.Razor.Parser.CSharpCodeParser.get_RazorKeywords()'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I created an mvc4 project in vs2015. After installation it shows the error:

> Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2
>   System.Web.Razor.Parser.CSharpCodeParser.get_RazorKeywords()'

This is my web.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I have studied that MVC4 is compatible with razor2, which is already in my config.

I have seen some solutions which advise to either removed the reference code from web.config or change the razor version to 1.0.0.0. I have tried both, but they are both adding the error.

Can anyone suggest a more specific solution for this?

Comment: It looks like you are using MVC 3.0 and Razor 2.0, you should have in your web.config for using MVC5 something like that <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />

Comment: that need mvc dll to be upgraded as well physically

Comment: Try to use a nuget package manager and add APS.NET MVC 4 to your project.

Comment: I think this article can help you http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806

Comment: it only allows to upgrade to latest version (5.2)  .. even after doing that . it shows same error